# Persistence for user Multi-User Chat in Converse.js

Tags: ejabberd, converse.js

I want to retrieve all chat conversations from ejabberd, even after I logout, close the browser and login again. Please suggest any way to do it. I am using converse.js. Should I add something in converse configuration to retrieve the chat conversation ?

Basically, I want Facebook kind of chat where we can retrieve chat conversation between each user after its logged in.

Here is my converse.js config:

```
converse.initialize({
                        websocket_url: webSocketUrl, // ConnectionUrl
                        keepalive: true,
                        message_carbons: true,
                        play_sounds: true,
                        auto_login: true,
                        jid: user,
                        password: password,                        
                        show_controlbox_by_default: false,
                        auto_list_rooms:true,
                        allow_logout: false,
                        allow_registration: false,
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converse.js supports the XMPP extension [XEP-0313 Message Archive Management (MAM)](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html).

You need to make sure that your XMPP server supports MAM. [Ejabberd 15.06](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-15-06/) has support for it. You'll need to turn it on in Ejabberd's configuration file.

In converse.js, you want to pass in a value of `roster` or `always` to [message_archiving](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#message-archiving) when you call `converse.initialize`.

For example:

```
converse.initialize({
                   // Your other options go here...
                   message_archiving: 'always'
                });
```

`roster` means that only message to and from contacts in your roster are archived. `always` of course means that messages are always archived.

There is also the related option [archived_messages_page_size](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#archived-messages-page-size), which you can use to set how many messages are fetched at a time.

Comment: Extremely thankful for your answer. Really helped me a lot